# ojdbc jar size gets double when copyfile executes in the azure deveops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I have a zip file which I copy using below code:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
       SourceFolder: '${Build.SourcesDirectory}/App/target/'
       Contents: '*.zip'
       TargetFolder: '${Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory}'
       CleanTargetFolder: true
       flattenFolders: true
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

After this when I check the artifacts published I get ojdbc8.jar file as 8,641 kb.
Original size was: 4923 kb.

```
   name: Linux
   demands: maven
```

I don't know what's wrong. Please help.

Let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Is the `ojdbc8.jar` file contained in the copied zip file? Before the `CopyFiles@2` task, have you defined other steps that may change the `ojdbc8.jar` file? I recommend you provide more details of your pipeline definition.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT It's resolved now. Thank  you for your response. The issue was the filtered tag in pom.xml while adding it to the zip. It was set to true. I set it to false and it's no more corrupted.
<filtered>false</filtered>